# Django : One to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a question regarding objects modelling. Let's say we have a one to many relationship where an object A instance could have 0 to many linked objects B whereas object B could be linked to one and only one object A (note here object B cannot be created without being linked to an object B).
So far I have added a foreign key to object B model, when adding that object I should select an Object A , so far so good.
My question now is do I have to also add the object B to object A model on database level? Or should I just do it on API level by creating nested APIs? So that getting object B would be this way :

```
get : http://localhost/api/objectA/objectB
```

I hope I was clear explaining my question but to summarize I am not sure if adding a foreign key to represent a : 0.n---->1.1 is enough.

It has been a long time for me that I did not design a database am I using a very old methodology?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question now is do I have to also add the object B to object A model on database level?

**No**. If you constructed a relation like a `ForeignKey`, you can let Django query in reverse. So if you have two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can obtain all `B` objects that belong to some `A` object `somea` with:

```
somea.b_set.all()
```

You can rename the relation in reverse by setting the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). So you can specify the relation as:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(
        A,
        related_name='bs',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

and then query with:

```
somea.bs.all()
```